# How can I convert a particle system into it's own truly single object, in order to project onto it?

Tags: mesh, particles, camera

I want to take a video and project it onto a particle system that corresponds to shapes in the shot. Blender makes it easy to do projection aka camera mapping, but I can't figure out how to convert/export my particle system into a single editable object to which I could apply one single material (in this case the video as an image texture) .

I already know that you can "join" particles after "converting" the system, but this is akin to parenting and doesn't let you apply a texture to the sim as though it were one object, but rather it lets you apply one texture to **every** object. This will not work for a camera projection.

I think the answer may lie in successfully exporting the simulation as an obj sequence or something like that, but I can't seem to export the animated particles in any usable format. OBJ creates a still group of particles, and FBX creates a total mess. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe someone has an alternate idea, but I would really appreciate some expertise.
Thanks!